# select image on drive with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created a website, when the admin dblclick on the image then he can choose for a new one. That I will accomplish with javascript. But, I don't have any idea to do that, the following code is the html.
[image]

```
<form action="controller.php" method="post" class="popupform" id="form_changeillustration" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<dl>
  <dt><label for="newillustration">choose a new photo: </label></dt>
  <dd><input type="file" name="newillustration" id="newillustration" /></dd>
  <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
  <dd class="buttonrow">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{$PAGE}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="newillustration" />
    <input type="submit" class="btnOk" value="edit" />
    <input type="button" class="btnCancel" value="cancel" />
  </dd>
</dl>
</form>
```

Comment: This is tougher than it looks, because a file input's click event can't be triggered programmatically for security reasons.

Comment: Select an image on *what* "drive"?  Are the images stored at the server, or are you intending that users upload images?

Comment: Do you mean a double click on an existing image in the page, or just when something got selected in the file dialog?

Comment: The images are stored on the c drive,yes.. off course only the administrator can choose a new image. I need just an example to trigger when the 'admin' dblclick on that area and how to open a file dialog. I have included screenshot of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><img src="images/moi.jpg" alt="" id="image" /></p>

        <p style="display: none;"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                var image = document.getElementById('image');
                var file = document.getElementById('file');

                image.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
                    file.click();
                }, false);

                file.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    var fileToUpload = this.files[0];

                    console.log(fileToUpload);
                }, false);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It will only work in Firefox (the .click() method works in FF and IE, but the File object is not implemented in IE), so if your admin's browser is FF you can use this trick and then follow this doc to upload your file : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications